# go (reflect): How to Instantiate an arbitrary type and set a known embedded field

Tags: reflection, go

Consider the following type declaration:

```
type (
    Embedded struct{}
    Actual1 struct{ *Embedded }
    Actual2 struct{ *Embedded }
    Actual3 struct{ *Embedded }
)
```

Now consider the following function, where `i` may be of type `Actual1`, `Actual2`, or `Actual3` (or any other type that embeds `Embedded` in like manner). I can't do a type assertion or a type switch because I can't know how many types contain `Embedded`, all I know about `i` is that it does indeed embed the `Embedded` type. This function will instantiate a new instance of the same type as `i` and set `embed` on that newly instantiated copy instance.

```
func New(i interface{}, field *Embedded) interface{} {
    // Step 1. instantiate new instance of `i`, of same underlying type as `i`
    // Step 2. set `i.Embedded` to `field`
    // Step 3. return the new instance.
}
```

Here's what usage would look like:

```
func main() {
    actual := &Actual1{}
    embed := &Embedded{}
    copied := New(actual, embed)
    if copied.(Actual1).Embedded != embed {
        log.Fatal("It didn't work!")
    }
}
```

**A correct implementation of the `New(...)` function cannot use type assertions or a type switch and would also not result in the call to `log.Fatal` shown above.**

I think what I'm asking for is a combination of these two questions:

- [How do you create a new instance of a struct from it's Type at runtime in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850140/how-do-you-create-a-new-instance-of-a-struct-from-its-type-at-runtime-in-go?rq=1)
- [in golang, using reflect, how do you set the value of a struct field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395076/in-golang-using-reflect-how-do-you-set-the-value-of-a-struct-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection, you can do it like that:

- get the type of the struct from the type of the pointer to it
- instantiate and deref it
- set the value of the field (looking it up by name) with the value of your pointer

Code:

```
v := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(i).Elem()).Elem()
f := reflect.ValueOf(field)
v.FieldByName("Embedded").Set(f)
return v.Interface()
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/fX413svXDv

Comment: Perfect! I was missing the .Elem() call right after the TypeOf(i).