# Create Struct instance with initialization from slices of data golang

Tags: go, struct, initialization, runtime

I have a data with array of array.

> `data := [][]int{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}`

and struct

> `type A struct {
>       I, J, K int
>   }`

Now I want to create instance run time for struct A with each array from data, How do I achieve that? If reflect is a way, then tell how?

This is just an example that I want to show you. But let's say if struct A contains 26 fields from A to Z with type of int and I have 100 slices of data from which I can create/init my struct A, then how it could be possible without using dot notation on struct and just looping over field index and assign that field from slice data?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    I, J, K int
}

func main() {
    data := [][]int{
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 3, 2},
    }

    var a A
    // create instance of type A with params
    // initialization for each array in data
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Please help me at this link: https://play.golang.org/p/rYuoajn5Ln

Comment: I saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850140/how-do-you-create-a-new-instance-of-a-struct-from-its-type-at-runtime-in-go, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Are you just looking for a for loop? https://play.golang.org/p/88GiQuQyBP (also, these are slices not arrays, which are different in Go)

Comment: Oh Sorry that was mistake, yup they are slices but let's say I have 50 fields in struct and 100 slices which contains my struct data, then how do I achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want to set the fields via reflection? https://play.golang.org/p/QzHvhMnput

Comment: @JimB exactly that is what I want!! thanks bro. But I have a question which one is a good way to do this? via reflection or via hard coded assignment? See reason behind asking this is I have struct with 40 fields and have 1000 slices of slices which contains data for struct and I need good solution.

Comment: This seems like a very awkward data structure to deal with, does it have to be a struct? If the slices of ints are already ordered accordingly, why do they need to be converted to structs at all? If the int's just need names, why not a map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130248/discussion-between-rsudip90-and-jimb).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for, but you can create those objects in a simple loop:

```
func main() {
    data := [][]int{
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 3, 2},
    }

    for _, intArr := range data {
        a := NewA(intArr)
        // a:= A{I: ints[0], J: ints[1], K: ints[2]}

        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

Full solution available at https://play.golang.org/p/j7fxbmu3jp

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there any other way so that we can directly to do this with field index like for `0` indexed field assign value of `0` indexed data from slice?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, for a more compact version...

Just range over your "data" array of arrays and create a new "A" from each index.

No need to do that in a separate function.

```
for _, arr := range data {
    a := A{I: arr[0], J: arr[1], K: arr[2]}

    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Full solution here: https://play.golang.org/p/jyN7f9c-o-

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I achieved this via reflection.