# Wrap a reflect.Value with pointer which points to the same element

Tags: go, reflection, reflect

[Here](https://github.com/a8m/reflect-examples#wrap-a-reflectvalue-with-pointer-t--t) I found the following code -

```
// ptr wraps the given value with pointer: V => *V, *V => **V, etc.
func ptr(v reflect.Value) reflect.Value {
    pt := reflect.PtrTo(v.Type()) // create a *T type.
    pv := reflect.New(pt.Elem())  // create a reflect.Value of type *T.
    pv.Elem().Set(v)              // sets pv to point to underlying value of v.
    return pv
}
```

As stated, calling this function on variable V of type reflect.Value, which describes an element of type T that holds data d, returns variable VP of type reflect.Value, which describes an element of type *T that points to data d.

When modifying VP by setting it's data to something other then d, V doesn't change (ie by calling VP.Set(..)).
I need a function that returns VP as described above, but so that modifying the data in VP modifies it in V.

The reason I need this function is that I want to extend [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179271/13425543) to initialize strings and ints with default values. I wanted to use [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396678/13425543) to do it, but for that I need to have a value of a pointer of a struct, not a value of a struct, when running SetString and SetInt.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't do what you want if `v` isn't addressable.

Comment: Your first example may be confusing, since there's no reason for the `pt` value.  You cannot get a pointer to a non-addressable `reflect.Value`, and even if you could, it's a copy of the actual value you want a pointer to.